# Loading a .img file to floppy in virtual box

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, nasm, osdev, floppy

I have a Hello World Program in `Assembly language`

```
`; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ; helloworld.asm 
  ;
  ; This is a Win32 console program that writes "Hello, World" on one line and
  ; then exits.  It needs to be linked with a C library.   
  ; ------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------

 global  _main
 extern  _printf

 section .text
_main:
 push    message
 call    _printf
 add     esp, 4
 ret
 message:
  db  'Hello, World', 10, 0`
```

I have complied it using `nasm` and have got the `img` file.
When I use the `Floppy Controller` it gives a error..

```
Failed to open Floppy Disk File D:\helloworld.img
 the Medium D:\helloworld.img Cannot be used as a requested device type

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: Medium
Interface: IMedium {05f2bbb6-a3a6-4fb9-9b49-6d0dda7142ac}
Callee: IVirtualBox {fafa4e17-1ee2-4905-a10e-fe7c18bf5554}
Callee RC: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80BB0001)
```

Comment: It's most likely because your `img` file isn't padded to a sector boundary, aka 512 bytes. For nasm, you can just add this line at the end: `times 512-($-$$) db 0`

Comment: Although, from what I can tell, what you're trying to do is not appropriate for the given program. Since it's a Win32 program, you can't just put it straight on a floppy and expect it to boot in Virtual Box.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create .img file using partcopy or etc. I mean you have done to create an Image File but that has to be right one.As a sample you can produce it by using copy /b but that doesn't make it right.Or you can make it ISO file to make it usable.

```
miso your.iso -ab your.img
```